# using strict mode in ejs (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, strict

I'd like to use strict mode in my ejs template files, so far I have such code in my `server.js` file ([documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) says there is a `strict` option):

```
'use strict'
let express = require('express');  
let routes = require('./routes/index.js');  
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;  
let app = express();  
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
routes(app);  
app.listen(port, function(){});
```

and if I try write in my template file

```
<%
  'use strict'
  let user = {'name': 'whatever'}
%>
```

I get

> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode in /home/simanaitis/node/views/pages/index.ejs while compiling ejs

I tried writing

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.locals.rmWhitespace = true;
```

however, it didn't work because in [ejs.js](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/ea0fa32e27a13b9b77970b312699ff117aa56e59/lib/ejs.js) variable `_OPTS` doesn't have `strict` option.

So I'd like to know how/if it is possible to combine *ejs*, *express* and *routes* to be able to use strict mode in my templates.

Comment: Looks like the docs say strict mode is defined in the options, not inside the .ejs file itself. Although I would assume strict mode is enabled by default anyway.

Comment: @Noface in my case trying to use the keyword `let` yields the shown error, so probably it's not enabled by default

Comment: strict does not enable `let`, which is actually ES6+ code, strict does things like disallow setting global variables without `var` and disallows `with` statements.